# Keyerror 'job.cost.sheet' in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

I am trying to develop a **custom module** in Odoo .
when I am upgrading it, I'm getting this error in the log.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 1049, in get
>       value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]] KeyError: 434
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 989, in **get**
>       value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 1051, in get
>       raise CacheMiss(record, field) odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.actions.act_window(434,).search_view', None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
>       return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314,
>   in _handle_exception
>       raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
>       raise value   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
>       result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in
>   _call_function
>       return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in
>   wrapper
>       return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
>       result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in **call**
>       return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
>       response = f(*args, **kw)   File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1262, in load
>       action = request.env[action_type].browse([action_id]).read()   File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo
>   12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 210, in read
>       result = super(IrActionsActWindow, self).read(fields, load=load)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line
>   2797, in read
>       vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 5120,
>   in **getitem**
>       return self._fields[key].**get**(self, type(self))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 993, in
>   **get**
>       self.determine_value(record)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1106, in determine_value
>       self.compute_value(recs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1060, in compute_value
>       self._compute_value(records)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1051, in _compute_value
>       getattr(records, self.compute)()   File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line
>   170, in _compute_search_view
>       fvg = self.env[act.res_model].fields_view_get(act.search_view_id.id,
>   'search')   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 831, in **getitem**
>       return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py",
>   line 176, in **getitem**
>       return self.models[model_name] KeyError: 'job.cost.sheet'

**This is my code**

```
class JobCostSheet(models.Model):
    _name = 'job.cost.sheet'

    sequence = fields.Char(string='Sequence', readonly=True, copy=False, index=True,default=lambda self:self.env['ir.sequence'].get('job.cost.sheet'))
    project_id = fields.Many2one('project.project',string='Project')
    analytic_ids = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account',string="Analytic Account")
    job_order_id = fields.Many2one('job.order','Job Order')
    job_issue_customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Job Issue Customer')
    create_date = fields.Datetime(string="Create Date",default=datetime.now())
    close_date = fields.Datetime(string="Close Date",default=datetime.now())
    create_by_id = fields.Many2one('res.users','Created By')
    material_job_cost_line_ids = fields.One2many('job.cost.line','material_job_cost_sheet_id','Material Job Cost Line')
    labour_job_cost_line_ids = fields.One2many('job.cost.line','labour_job_cost_sheet_id','Labout Job Cost Line')
    overhead_job_cost_line_ids = fields.One2many('job.cost.line','overhead_job_cost_sheet_id','Overhead Job Cost Line')
    tools_job_cost_line_ids = fields.One2many('job.cost.line','tools_job_cost_sheet_id','Tools Job Cost Line')
    machines_job_cost_line_ids = fields.One2many('job.cost.line','machines_job_cost_sheet_id','Tools Job Cost Line')
    total_material_cost = fields.Float(compute='_compute_total_material_cost',string="Total Material Cost",default=0.0)
    total_labour_cost = fields.Float(compute='_compute_total_labour_cost',string='Total Labour Cost',default=0.0)
    total_overhead_cost = fields.Float(compute='_compute_total_overhead_cost',string='Total Overhead Cost',default=0.0)
    total_cost = fields.Float(compute='_compute_total_cost',string='Total Cost',default=0.0)

    job_cost_description = fields.Text('Job Cost Description')
    currency_id = fields.Many2one("res.currency", compute='get_currency_id', string="Currency")
    stage = fields.Selection([('draft','Draft'),('confirm','Confirmed'),('approve','Approved'),('done','Done')],'Stage',
                     copy=False,default='draft')
    purchase_order_line_count = fields.Integer('Purchase Order Line', compute='_get_purchase_order_line_count')
    invoice_line_count = fields.Integer('Invoice Order Line', compute='_get_invoice_line_count')
    #is_done_stage = fields.Boolean(string='Is Done Stage')
    #is_confirm_stage = fields.Boolean(string='Is Confirm Stage',default=False)
    #is_approve_stage = fields.Boolean(string='Is Approve Stage',default=False)

    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company',string="Company")
    sale_reference = fields.Text(string="Description Sale Reference")
```

Comment: I think problem is `default=lambda self: self.env['ir.sequence'].get('job.cost.sheet')`

Comment: Agree with @PruthviBarot, Are you able to get the value of that expression? because the default attribute value should be an type of the field. in you case it should be some character.

Answer (score 0):

define `'job.cost.sheet'` as code in `ir.sequence`

and use as `self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('job.cost.sheet')`